# where loop changes every post in custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

How can I create a type of loop in WordPress where an image moves left or right for each post? I.e. first post image will be left, second post image will go right, third post image will go left, and so on...

Also i am create custom post type.

I'm trying to make a loop in wordpress with one different post types.

The code below is working fine, i am also use advanced custom fields.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bDy6.jpg

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'team') );
  if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
  $Inc = 0; //start your counter
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $person_image = get_field('person_image');
    $person_description = get_field('person_description');
    ?>
        <?php if($Inc % 2 == 0){ //if $inc can be created by multiplying 2.?>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <div>
                  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/dot1.png" class="img-responsive dotimages">
                </div>
              </div> <!--.col-md-1 -->
              <div class="col-md-10 row">
                <div class="clientimagesarea">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                      <img src="<?php echo $person_image; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block peopleimages">
                      <?php //the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="clienttext clienttextmarleft">
                      <?php echo $person_description; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddmargin0">
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                            <div><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/email-icon2.png" class="img-responsive clientemailicon text-left"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
                            <div class="emailid">abx@sitename.com</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddmargin0">
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                            <div><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/call-icon2.png" class="img-responsive clientemailicon2 "></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
                            <div class="emailid2">+41 79 777 66 45</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php //the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php }else { //it cant?>
          <div class="row col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="deviderline">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
              <div class="row clientimagesarea">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="clienttext">
                    <p>
                      <?php echo $person_description; ?>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row iconmarginleft">
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddmargin0">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                          <div><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/email-icon2.png" class="img-responsive clientemailicon text-left"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
                          <div class="emailid">abx@sitename.com</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddmargin0">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                          <div><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/call-icon2.png" class="img-responsive clientemailicon2 "></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
                          <div class="emailid2">+91 1234567890</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div>
                    <img src="<?php echo $person_image; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block peopleimages clienttextmarleft">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <div>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/dot3.png" class="img-responsive dotimage3">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php
        $Inc++;
        endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Seems like this may already have some kind of answer here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72348/alternating-post-layout

Comment: but they cannot use custom post type

Comment: The outcome you want is just CSS just target using :nth-child(even) and :nth-chil(odd) and use css to move them either side

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a class which changes for each post.

Example:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$x=0;

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
  while( $query->have_posts() ) :

  $layout_array = array('image_left','image_right');
  $classImage = $layout_array[$x%2];
  $x++;

  /*do your stuff here*/
  /*Example: <div class="'.$classImage.'">asdf</div> */

  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();

else :
   esc_html_e( 'no posts found', 'text-domain' );
endif;
```